# DimDate won't load when date range changed to start from 01-01-0001

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have resolved the previous issue, thank you. However, I still have an issue with the below (Part of the previous). How can I convert the result into a DATE datatype as '0001-01-01' isn't supported with DATETIME? I've tried DATETIME2 but not working and the StartDate needs to be '0001-01-01'. Any help is highly apprciated.

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '0001-01-01'

SELECT 
        DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0) AS FirstDayOfQuarter,
        DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, -1, @CurrentDate), -1) AS LastDayOfQuarter,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, (6- 
        DATEPART(DAY, @CurrentDate)), @CurrentDate)),0),120) AS 
        FirstMondayOftheMonth

---

Error Message:

> The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Kindly add the schema of `#DimDate` table

Comment: Your `SELECT` actually runs (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23758).  Presumably, you have a `datetime` data type in your table.

Comment: If you do need to store not filled dates use nullable types instead.

Comment: To echo what @GordonLinoff says, you'll need to switch `datetime`-type columns to `datetime2`-type columns (or perhaps something more appropriate).  Although I'm curious what a datetime-type column is doing in a date dimension...

Answer (score 0):

The Range of Datetime datatype is from January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999.

The error here states you are exceeding lower boundary or lower limit.

If you have to store that value from 0001, use Varchar instead.

In many realtime projects I have seen, it generally starts from 1900-01-01 which people take it as default mininum date

Comment: don't mix varchar with date types lots of maintenaince pain

Comment: Thanks Sree, I understand that 1900 is generally used but they want 0001. In addition, using varchar will not work as I'll be using DATDIFF and DATEPART later inside the logic.

Comment: Here is the logic which isn't working as it returns a DATETIME result. Any help would be much appreciated.
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '0001-01-01'
SELECT  DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0) AS 
                FirstDayOfQuarter,
  DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, -1, @CurrentDate), -1) AS 
                LastDayOfQuarter,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, 
                DATEADD(DAY, (6-DATEPART(DAY, @CurrentDate)), @CurrentDate)),0),120) AS FirstMondayOftheMonth